# Symfony routing: only `/` page is working

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm having a strange symfony problem.
I'm trying to play with Symfony 3.4 and nginx.

I follow the "Create your First Page" tutorial but, only**/symfony/Symfony/web/app_dev.php** page is working
when I using URL **/symfony/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number**, IT SHOW

> "nginx error! The page you are looking for is not found."

LuckyController.php

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number", name="luckyNumber")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig', [
            'number' => $number,
        ]);
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.tld www.domain.tld;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

        location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
        }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    }
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Comment: tried this? https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the configuration you are using for nginx is the one for symfony 4.x and not 3.4

I see that you `root` and `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {`  are wrong.

the root should contains "web" and the location should contains "app_dev" and and other on "app".

check the documentation on symfony, it is well done :-)

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

*P.S. If you are starting symfony, I would suggest you to start with symfony 4, it is the newest version*

Comment: it's useful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i forgot to add:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

after adding this, everything works fine!